# What's wrong with this JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i'm trying to match a "userTypeId" in the "users" table to its corresponding "id" in the "userRoles" table so that I can echo the "roleName", also in "userRoles".

Here are the tables:

```
userRoles
---------------------
id  roleName
1   superuser
2   admin
3   editor
4   author
5   contributor
6   subscriber

users
---------------------
id  userName        userTypeId
1   heyjohnmurray   1
2   admin           2
```

I tried this query and whenever i check it, it echoes out "WRONG"

```
$roleQuery = "SELECT id, roleName, userTypeId FROM userRoles JOIN users ON id=userTypeId";
$roleResult = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $roleQuery);

if(!$roleResult){
    echo 'WRONG';
} else {
    echo 'RIGHT';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add an `ALIAS` on the tables,

```
SELECT a.id, a.roleName, b.userTypeId 
FROM   userRoles a, users b
WHERE  a.id = b.userTypeId
```

or better use the format (*ANSI SQL-92*)

```
SELECT a.id, a.roleName, b.userTypeId 
FROM   userRoles a
       INNER JOIN users b
          ON a.id = b.userTypeId
```

Comment: so even though i don't intentionally select the id in "users" i still need the alias to clarify that i'm only interested in the "userRoles" id and not the "users" id?

Comment: actually the main reason is that you have name collision, i recommended to use alias so you can specify the column name with the alias of the table. anyway, alias is optional, you can still use the full tablename `userRoles.id = users.userTypeId`

Comment: thanks so much for answering such a beginner's question. it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: it's not a beginner question. and most sql developers overlook this problem..hehe anyway, you are welcome :D

Comment: is there a way to have php actually echo out that you need to add an alias. I know over time I'll know by looking at it, but is there a way for it to output a message like "`id` is ambiguous"?

Answer (score 1):

You should use alias for the tables else you will face unambiguous error on the query because both join table has the id's so the server may forced to the unambiguous situation to select the fields from the table

```
 SELECT UR.id, U.roleName, U.userTypeId FROM  userRoles AS UR JOIN users AS U ON UR.id = U.userTypeId
```

Comment: thanks for the help and for confirming what John Woo previously stated. I really appreciate the answer.